# running libserialport in any event loop

Tags: serial-port, polling, event-loop, lib, libuv

I am trying to integrate libserialport library to a solution which can use poll, libev and libuv.

while its relatively easy to get the fd for the serial port file from libserialport and watch it using libev or libuv,

```
uv_poll_init(loop, &poller, serial_port_fd);
uv_poll_start(&poller, UV_READABLE /*| UV_PRIORITIZED*/, cb);
```

I do not know how to get it working using the default loop using poll.
the main loop is like:

```
while(!interrupted){
    interrupted = service_one_loop();
    //// THIS IS ONE PLACE TO poll (serial_port_fd) CODE and call callback function for serial
}
```

Is there any other way? Something like :

```
while(!interrupted){
    interrupted = service_one_loop();
    read_size = sp_nonblocking_read(machine_port, read_buffer, read_buffer_size);
    if (read_size >= 0) {
        cb();
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping out in advance.